# Filter only numbers (0-9) in output in classic Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a text, for example:

```
cd123aaq54
```

and I'd like to separate only numbers in another file, so I could have

```
12354
```

in the output.

I have been trying a lot of commands like:

```
Get-Content text.txt | Select-String  -Pattern '[0-9]'
```

In linux it's much easier, just:

```
grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*' text >numbers
```

How can I do this in a Windows `cmd` shell?

Comment: There are a number of Windows versions of `grep`, though not all have the `-o` option.

Comment: Where can I download a grep version that allow me to do it? I have tryied some of them.

Comment: I down-loaded [win-bash](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win-bash/). I don't use `bash.exe` itself very much, but in a 5.6MB zip file, as well as `bash`, there are over 100 of the common Unix utilities, including `sed`, `wget`, `find`, `xargs` and of course `grep`, and this version supports `-o`. There is no installation: extract to a directory, add it to your `PATH` and then run as required. Or you can add selected utilities to an existing directory already in your path. They are all 32-bit implementations, which means they will run on any Windows system since 98. Sadly there is no `man`.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoLizanaHidalgo Added answer with PowerShell and Windows batch files solutions. Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: `Get-Content` is a powershell command, not cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I strip Alpha characters from an input file, leaving only numbers?

Below are two solutions:

- PowerShell
- Windows batch file

---

#### PowerShell solution

Use the following command:

```
Get-Content input.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "[^0-9]", ""} > output.txt
```

Notes:

- `input.txt` contains the text to be filtered.
- `output.txt` contains the filtered text
- All non numeric characters (not just alpha characters) will be removed.

Example:

```
PS F:\test> type .\input.txt
cd123aaq54
zyx456abc321
PS F:\test> Get-Content input.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "[^0-9]", ""} > output.txt
PS F:\test> type .\output.txt
12354
456321
PS F:\test>
```

---

#### Windows batch file solution

Use the following batch file (RemoveAlpha.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _alpha=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
rem read input file line by line
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`type %1`) do (
  rem strip alpha characters by using them as delimeters
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=%_alpha%" %%j in ("%%i") do (
    rem write stripped text to output file
    echo %%j%%k>>%2
    )  
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The above assumes there are no special characters (`!@#$%^&*()` ...) in the input file (they won't be removed).
- The 'trick' is to use the string of Alpha characters as delimeters for the second `for` command.

Usage:

```
RemoveAlpha input output
```

- `input`:  Pathname for the input file containing the text to be filtered.
- `output`:  Pathname for the output file to contain the filter text copied.

Example:

```
F:\test>RemoveAlpha input.txt output.txt

F:\test>type input.txt
cd123aaq54
zyx456abc321

F:\test>type output.txt
12354
456321
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Comment: How do you remove special characters?

Comment: @Cestarian Please ask a new question regarding this